# Chernoff bounds and Monte Carlo algorithms

Tags: randomized-algorithms, randomness, chernoff-bounds

One of Wikipedia examples of use of Chernoff bounds is the one where an algorithm $A$ computes the correct value of function $f$ with probability $p > 1/2$. Basically, Chernoff bounds are used to bound the error probability of $A$ using repeated calls to $A$ and majority agreement.

I don't understand how, to be frank. It would be nice if somebody could break it down piece by piece. Moreover, does it matter whether $A$ is a decision algorithm or can return more values? How are Chernoff bounds in general used for Monte Carlo algorithms?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you don't understand. How to derive Chernoff bounds, or how to apply Chernoff bounds?

Comment: Yeah, how to apply. Why it can be applied to this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's suppose that we have a polynomial time randomized algorithm $A$ for a decision problem $\Pi$ with the property that
$$
\mathrm{Pr}[A \text{ is right}] > 1/2
$$
for all inputs.  (In particular, independent of the input length $n$.)

We can use Chernoff bounds to show something stronger, namely that for any fixed $c$, there is a polynomial time, randomized algorithm for $\Pi$ that is correct with probability at least $1-n^{-c}$.

The algorithm is very simple: On an input of length $n$, we run $A$ a polynomial number of times $N$ (to be determined below) and then report the majority answer.  Call this algorithm $A'$.

What we need is a bound on 
$$
\mathrm{Pr}[A' \text{ is wrong}]
$$
in terms of the number of repetitions $N$.  The hypothesis about $A$ implies that there is an $\epsilon > 0$ such that 
$$
\mathrm{Pr}[A \text{ is right}] \ge 1/2 + \epsilon
$$
Since the $N$ runs of $A$ are independent, for any $k\in [N]$ we have
$$
\mathrm{Pr}[k \text{ of } N \text{ runs of } A \text{ are right}]\ge Pr[X = k]
$$
where $X$ is a binomial random variable with parameters $N$ and $1/2+\epsilon$.  Since the algorithm $A'$ is wrong exactly when at most $N/2$ of the runs of $A$ are right, we obtain an upper bound on the failure probability by a "tail estimate" bounding 
$$
\mathrm{Pr}[X \le N/2]
$$
This is a prototypical time to use a Chernoff bound, since a binomial r.v. is the sum of $N$ independent random variables.  One instance of the Chernoff bound says that if $Y$ is the sum of $N$ independent r.v.'s with support in $[0,1]$ and $t > 0$, then 
$$
\mathrm{Pr}[Y < E[Y] - t] \le e^{-2t^2/N}
$$
Thus, since $E[X] = N/2 + N\epsilon$, we take $t = N\epsilon$ to obtain 
$$
\mathrm{Pr}[A' \text{ is wrong}]\le e^{-2\epsilon^2 N}
$$
So we can take $N = (1/2)\epsilon^{-2}c\log n$, and we get the claimed error probability for $A'$.

Comment: It would help if you could add the part with Chernoff bounds, i.e., how to use it here. Moreover, does it matter whether $A$ is a decision problem or it can return more values?

Comment: Are you unsure about how to use Chernoff bounds at all, or what a Monte Carlo algorithm is?  The question is a little fuzzy about what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, I am unsure how to use them. For example, imagine that I want to make sure the error probability is at most $\epsilon$. How would I go about it? Basically, this example would guide me through on how to use and appreciate Chernoff bounds.

Comment: Great, much clearer! I guess when $A$ is not a decision problem, yet, for example yes/no/maybe, things get more complicated.

Comment: This use of Chernoff bounds is more of an example of a general approach than a specific result.  Try to formalize your specific setup and see!